# Is there a way to debug an iOS app or use TestFlight on a MacBook M?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, apple-m1

So I have an iOS app that runs on iPhone/iPad, and runs also on M1 Macs. I have an M1 MacBook Air, and I can install the app just fine from the App Store, but I have some issues to track down that only show up on the M1. For example, when I stretch the screen beyond what an iPad can show. I would love to either install the app from Xcode, and debug it directly, or install it from TestFlight or by another method other than from the public App Store so that I can at least try some things before releasing the app. Is there any way to do this that anyone has figured out?

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: No, I’m going to use one of my support tickets with Apple and see if I can get any information

Comment: did you got a response from apple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a way to install it from TestFlight but running from Xcode is easy. Just select `My Mac (designed for iPad)` as the run target. It's at the top of the dropdown list where you'd normally select the Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out today that you can download TestFlight from AppStore on Mac M1 with Monterey.

Comment: How can you access the debug console of that? My app keeps crashing and I can't find why...